# Problem with Texlipse and auto-ps-pdf

Tags: pstricks, texlipse, ps2pdf, auto-pst-pdf

I'm using the Eclipse-plugin Texlipse as my preferred LaTeX-editor. But since I'm using auto-pst-pdf for PStricks graphics in pdf-files Texlipse doesn't manage the complete compilation. That works just to the point where the wrapped pstricks-code has been compiled in a .ps-file (-autoop.ps). The remaining process with ps2pdf, pdfcrop etc. is failing. Of course, pdflatex will be executed with --shell-escape.

That's suspicious, when I'm running the same tex-file with the latex+dvips+ps2pdf procedure everything works fine, although ps2pdf has been used as well. Furthermore, when I execute that tex-file with Texmaker or Texworks the pdflatex-procedure works without any failures, same when i execute this file with the terminal manually.

Just the pdflatex-procedure with Texlipse fails. I don't know why. Texlipse uses the same pdflatex-program in the same path as Texmaker/works or manually. Isn't it?

That would be nice, when you can help me

Comment: It is difficult to solve a problem that is specific to a certain editor because we might not install all the available editors in our machines.